# 3 different regulators at the output of an SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Hello: I'm a beginner in electronics, so I don't know if my question is a stupid question. I have a chinese commercial SMPS rated at 24VDC 15Amp 360W output and I need to get from this output 3 differents outputs at 5V, 16V and 20V, this last one with 4Amps max. spike loads. (It`s a motor drived by a L298 board and some latching CMOS logic controlled with tact switches.

It Is possible to use 3 different regulators 78XX, one 7805, one 7815 and one 7820 connected to the 24V Output of this SMPS to get this three different voltages?

Consumption of the 16V output will be about 20-30W for some LEDS and relays and the 5V output is used only for sending the H TTl levels to 6 cmos chips and a few 3V leds.

Answer (score 2):

Check how much current those regulators can provide. Then check what the dropped voltage is. Dropped voltage for the 7805 would be 19 volts.

Then check what the allowable power dissipation is (current x dropped voltage) then you'll conclude that the answer is NO.

For instance with the 7815 which I'm presuming you are using a well-known technique to produce 16V, the dropped voltage is 8 volts and the 30 watt demand by the load implies a load current (at 16 volts) of 1.875 A so, power dissipation is 8 V x 1.875 A = 15 watts = big heatsink if the device could supply 1.875 A (which it can't).

While you are doing those checks take a look at the L298 data sheet and note that in providing 4 amps (absolute maximum rating and to be generally avoided for a good design) this is split into 2 H bridges that can only handle 2A each. Basically if you think you can parallel two H bridges from this device you might be dissapointed.

Even if you could successfully parallel two H bridges of this type you would be dropping about 5V (worst case numbers 3.7 volts typically) in the chip at 4A and that is 20 watts to dissipate. This needs a significant heatsink - are you aware of this?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Yes, my idea was to parallel the L298 because this is a motor of an old 0 model train machine. It has a typical load of about 1-1,5 Amps, so only at start it draws more than this consumption. Driving is by PWM pulses, so I think, but I may be in an error, that in a normal use it never achieve this 4 amps consumption. Board of the 298 has a heatsink, but not would be a problem for me to change this for other bigger.

Answer (score 0):

My first though would be to see if the 24 volt supply can be adjusted down to 20 volts, otherwise you'll need a DC-DC converter rated at 4 Amps minimum to get the 20 volts for your motors.

You need about 1.8 amps at 16 volts - that would also call for a DC-DC converter, as a linear regulator like the 78xx series or LM317 would have to dissipate about 15 watts.

It sounds like the 5 volt load will only be a few mA, so a 7805 from the 16 volt supply should work.

Comment: And, to Peter, yes, a DC DC converter with more than 4 amps to the 20V output is a good idea. So, I understand, I need 2 DC DC regulators boards, one setted to 16V an the other to 20V and for the 5V a 7805 regulator. But all three pieces can link to this same SMPS?

Comment: Excuse me Andy and Peter. I crossed my answers. And excuse my english. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Yes, you could connect all three regulators to the output of the 24 volt supply, but I'd suggest connecting the 7805 to the output of the 16 volt supply, to reduce power dissipation in the 7805.

Comment: Ah, Ok. So 78XX can be connected in cascade? Per example a 16V at the output of a 24V, or a 5V at the output of a 12V, always having in mind respective load needs, I think.  Thank you very much, Peter